# Heuristic evaluation in information security

Tags: audit

Heuristic evaluation term is mostly on usability domain, especially it refer to 10 usability heuristics from Jakob Nielsen. In information security domain, we have security principles from Saltzer and Schroeder, generally accepted system security principles from NIST 800-14, and so on. Are these security principles can be called as "heuristics" because they are general ([Link](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesVsHeuristics))? And our activity that evaluate practices against these principles can be called as "heuristics evaluation"?

Based on this [Link](http://www.qualityperspectives.ca/resources_mnemonics.html), heuristics can be have mnemonics. So, security mnemonics like CIA, STRIDE, and so on can be called as "heuristics"?

Answer (score 1):

This is not typical terminology or practice in the security space. The terms one would look for are in the vein of "requirements" or "standards" or perhaps "principles" and evaluations against which can be called "gap analysis" and similar.

The difference in terminology matches a difference in the actual work. In security the work against those standards or requirements is mostly about activities in the execution domain, while in usability the work is more in the discovery domain.

Note also that the most secure system by definition is one that has zero usability; and to some extent security and usability are conflicting goals. The emerging practice of "usable security" is one in which heuristics for discovery of securer patterns have more of a role to play.